# Finding the terms of a continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\lfloor · \rfloor$ be the floor function, i.e. |$x$| := sup{$k ∈ \mathbb Z : k ≤ x$}
>   assigns to every rational (or real) number $x$ the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $x$.
>
> Let $r =\frac{355}{113}$ .
>
> (a) Let $q'_0 = r, q_0 =  \lfloor q'_0 \rfloor$, $q'_j =\frac{1}{q'_{j−1} − q_{j−1}}, q_j = \lfloor q'_j \rfloor$ where $j = 1, 2, . . . , n$.
>
> Calculate $q_0, . . . , q_n$ in this way (until the process terminates, i.e. $q'_{n+1} = 0$).
>
> (b) Verify using the recursion relations that the continued fraction with the terms $q_0, q_1, . . . , q_n$ is indeed equal to $\frac{355}{113}$ .
>
> (c) Can you compute the numbers $a, b$ ∈ $\mathbb Z$ in Bezout’s identity $a · 355 + b ·113 = 1$
>   using the procedure above?

I'm having troubles in starting with part a). For instance, $q'_1 =\frac{1}{q'_{0} − q_{0}}$, and then $q_1 = \lfloor q'_1 \rfloor$ which is the integer less than or equal to $q'_1$,  the thing is that I have $q'_0$ but how to get $q_0$? Any help please?

Then part b) is easy, I apply the recursion relations

and part c) can be solved by Euler's Algorithm.

Comment: Shouldn't that say $q'_0 = r, q_0 =  \lfloor q_0' \rfloor$?

Comment: After Will Jagy's correction, the question has become trivial. It says right there that $q_0 = \lfloor q_0'\rfloor$, Since $q_0' = \frac {355}{113} = 3\frac{16}{113}$, quite obviously $q_0 = 3$. (Of course, the original question had $q_0 = |g_0'|$, which obviously doesn't work, since it would make $q_1 = \frac 10$, so I can see why you were confused.)

Comment: @saulspatz I dont know if what you said is correct. The professor wrote it the way I did before you corrected it

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes true, but the professor wrote it $q_0 = ⌊q_0⌋$ so this is why I was confused

Comment: @cbcbc I didn't change anything; I just asked a question.  However, I'm sure that it was a typo.  This is just Euclid's (not Euler's) algorithm.